# Bound ContentControl not displaying

Tags: wpf, binding, contentcontrol, geometry-path

I have two `ContentControls` on a page that bind to the same `StaticResource` and one of them draws correctly an the other doesn't draw at all.

The resource is defined thus:

```
<Path x:Key="ArrowNorth"
    Stroke="DarkGray"
    StrokeThickness="1"
    Data="M 20,4 L 36,20 L 32,24 L 23,15 L 23,33 L 17,33 L 17,15 L 8,24 L 4,20 Z">
    <Path.Fill>
        <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.15,0.2" Center="0.3,0.4">
            <GradientStop Color="White"  Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowResource}, Path=ArrowColor}"  Offset="1"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

The resource is basically an arrow that I am trying to display on top of a circle.  The place that it is not drawing correctly is define like this:

```
<Grid Canvas.Top="30" Canvas.Left="6" ToolTip="Up"
       Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowResource}, Path=ShowVertical}">
    <Ellipse x:Name="lightEllipseU" Height="40" Width="40">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.3,0.3" Center="0.4,0.4">
                <GradientStop Color="White"  Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop
                    Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowResource}, Path=LightColorU}"
                    Offset="1"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <!-- This doesn't display -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ArrowNorth}}"/> 
</Grid>
```

The `Ellipse` displays fine and just to test the Z order, I commented out the `Ellipse` and the `ContentControl` would still not display.  Further down the page I use the arrow in a differnt place and the arrow displays just fine. Here is the code:

```
<Grid Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="110" ToolTip="Y Axis">
    <Ellipse x:Name="lightEllipseN" Height="40" Width="40">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.3,0.3" Center="0.4,0.4">
                <GradientStop Color="White"  Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowResource}, Path=LightColorN}"  Offset="1"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <!-- This displays just fine -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ArrowNorth}}"/>
</Grid>
```

The code is absolutely the same (cut and paste).  I can't understand why it will work in one place an not another.

Comment: Additional information:  I tried to add it a third time and that displayed correctly, but the original stopped displaying.  It appears that a resource can only be bound once and the last binding on a page wins.  Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, as each `Visual` can have only one parent and since you have only one `Path` then last time it's used it will be put in that place of visual tree. What you can do is create `Geometry` resource:

```
 <Window.Resources>
     <!-- ..... -->
     <Geometry x:Key="myPath">M 20,4 L 36,20 L 32,24 L 23,15 L 23,33 L 17,33 L 17,15 L 8,24 L 4,20 Z</Geometry>
 </Window.Resources>
```

and then you can use is in more then one `Path`:

```
<Grid ...>
    <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.3,0.3" Center="0.4,0.4">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <Path Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="1" Data="{StaticResource myPath}">
        <Path.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.15,0.2" Center="0.3,0.4">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

However, since it's used in more then one place and it basically looks the same, only colours change, it would be useful to create custom `UserControl` with 2 `DependancyProperty` for colours binding and then you can reuse it as many places you like

Comment: dkozl, Thanks for your reply and thanks for confirming my suspicion and explaining why.  Also, thanks for the two great alternatives.  In my app I only needed the Path in two places, so I just duplicated it, but it is nice to have the other options.